# Creating triggers with custom SQL in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am trying to create a MySQL trigger in my Django application.  I tried to follow the example at http://bryanmarty.com/blog/2012/12/03/mysql-triggers-django/ , but when my custom SQL is run, I do not see the trigger created in the database (using show triggers;).

My model's name is Process, and I also have another model named Machine.  This is what my "custom" SQL looks like:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER processes_running_count
AFTER INSERT ON jobs_process
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE jobs_machine SET processes_running=processes_running+1 limit 1; --
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

After I run python manage.py syncdb, I can see that the appropriate tables exist (jobs_process, jobs_machine, etc.), but no triggers are present.  If I copy/paste the code from my custom SQL into a MySQL prompt, the trigger is created (so I don't think the issue is invalid MySQL syntax).

Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

There is no canonical way to do this in Django because it kind of breaks the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) regarding the Model-View-Whatever paradigm (mixing business logic with persistence). In Django, for most situations where you would think about triggers, you can override the [`Model.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) and/or `Model.delete()` methods (also take a look at [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)).

In this case, triggers are overkill - why store a value that can be calculated? Just do something like `Process.objects.filter(active=True).count()`.

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth, Donald (December 1974). "Structured Programming with go to Statements"

That said, your concern may be that relational databases are expensive choices for status polling because of the overhead imposed by the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) contract - hundreds of clients hammering the `jobs_machine` table can be stressful for most servers. Lightweight key/value stores like [redis](http://redis.io/) and [memcached](http://memcached.org/) are popular choices for this kind of task (think of them as giant shared dicts).

Answer (score 2):

Here is information about multiply delimiters in SQL statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/52292690/9521312

In your case you could use my script (not perfect, as is), which converts MySQL statements with custom DELIMITER to the raw SQL statements.

### Add script execution in migration file

There are both examples of using script: run sql file or run raw MySQL statement

```
from anywhere import migrate_run_sql

operations = [
              migrations.RunPython(migrate_run_sql.run_sql_file('contract_triggers.sql')),
              migrations.RunPython(migrate_run_sql.run_sql(
                                                           """
                                                           DELIMITER $$
                                                           CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table
                                                           FOR EACH ROW
                                                           BEGIN
                                                             IF NEW.number <> 'anynumber' AND NEW.number <> 'anynumber'
                                                               THEN
                                                                 SET NEW.number = 'anynumber';
                                                             END IF;
                                                           END$$
                                                           """
                                                           ))
             ]
```

### Script file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import connection
import re
from StringIO import StringIO
from django.conf import settings
import os

# this function get raw MySQL statement
def run_sql(sql): 
    def load_data_from_sql(app, schema_editor):
        f = StringIO(sql)
        return _runsql(f)

    return load_data_from_sql

# this function get sql file
def run_sql_file(filename):
    def load_data_from_sql(app, schema_editor):
        filepath = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, '../deploy/mysql/', filename)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            return _runsql(f)

    return load_data_from_sql

# in this function content splits and checks line by line
def _runsql(f):
    with connection.cursor() as c:
        file_data = f.readlines()
        statement = ''
        delimiter = ';\n'
        for line in file_data:
            if re.findall('DELIMITER', line): # found delimiter
                if re.findall('^\s*DELIMITER\s+(\S+)\s*$', line):
                    delimiter = re.findall('^\s*DELIMITER\s+(\S+)\s*$', line)[0] + '\n'
                    continue
                else:
                    raise SyntaxError('Your usage of DELIMITER is not correct, go and fix it!')
            statement += line // add lines while not met lines with current delimiter
            if line.endswith(delimiter):
                if delimiter != ';\n':
                    statement = statement.replace(';', '; --').replace(delimiter, ';') # found delimiter, add dash symbols (or any symbols you want) for converting MySQL statements with multiply delimiters in SQL statement
                c.execute(statement) # execute current statement
                statement = '' # begin collect next statement
```

Hope it will help!